# How can I make var in *ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, var, angular-ng-if

I have situation:

```
<test-component *ngIf="(items | somePipe).length"
                [items]="items | somePipe"
></test-component>
```

How can I make var from (items | somePipe) in order to not repeat the same code

If there was possible to do sth like that:

```
<test-component *ngIf="((items | somePipe) as pipedItems).length"
                [items]="pipedItems"
></test-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
<test-component *ngIf="items | somePipe as myItems"
            [items]="myItems"
></test-component>
```

if you have to check exactly the `length` so you can wrap it with `ng-container`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="items | somePipe as myItems"> 
    <test-component *ngIf="myItems.length"
        [items]="myItems"
 ></test-component>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I need to check exactly length

Comment: but if you checking if there's any element in the array -  `length` is redundant

Comment: why length will be redundant?